# inject instance of store into specific component type

Tags: ember.js

I have the following initializer where I want to inject the ember-data store into a specific component type:

I tried to use

> application.inject

in an initializer but I could not get it to work.  I have hacked round it with the code below but I do not understand why the commented code would not work:

```
Ember.onLoad('Ember.Application', function(Application) {
  Application.initializer({
    name: "injectStoreIntoAutosuggest",
    after: "store",
    initialize: function(container, application) {
      window.AutoSuggestComponent.reopen({
        store: container.lookup('store:main')
      });

      // FIXME: why does this not work?
      // application.inject('component:autoSuggest', 'store', 'store:main');
    }
  });
});
```

The reason I need the store is because I have [this](https://github.com/dagda1/ember-autosuggest) component that has this api:

```
{{auto-suggest source=App.Employee destination=controller.dsChosenEmployees searchPath="fullName" minChars=0}}
```

I think it is nice to be able to just specify an ember-data model and be good to go.

Previously you could do:

> App.Employee.find

But with the latest ember-data this is no longer an option.

Comment: technically it should be 'component:auto-suggest', but that's not why it's not working, it appears to be something with the fact that it's extend, and it's not creating with injection, I'm still code diving...

Comment: And it looks like the component is instantiated before the initializer ocurrs, so the building up of using those dependencies is never making it into the class.  I'm not quite sure how to properly fix it.

Comment: @kingpin2k just `application.inject('component:auto-suggest', 'store', 'store:main');` worked for me. I don't understand that additional problems that you describe.

Comment: Who knows, something funky was going on with my bin.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is with the injection name. Change `component:autoSuggest` to `component:auto-suggest` and will work:

```
Ember.onLoad('Ember.Application', function(Application) {
  Application.initializer({
    name: "injectStoreIntoAutosuggest",
    after: "store",
    initialize: function(container, application) {      
      application.inject('component:auto-suggest', 'store', 'store:main');
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a fiddle with this working http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/6VEks/

Comment: Here is an example I made using static data: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vamahonuku/1/edit?js,output